# What's is the easiest way to append ';' to the end of lines which contain the char ':'?

Tags: regex, text-editing

I have a text file, whose content is like:

```
body
    font-size: 12px
    color: blue

td
    font-size: 14px

...
```

I want to append `;` to the lines which contain `:`, so the content will be:

```
body
    font-size: 12px;
    color: blue;

td
    font-size: 14px;

...
```

What's the easiest way to do this in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use regular expression substitution. Many editors support regular expressions, including Vim.**

Here's how to do it from the command line, using sed (Stream EDitor):

```
sed -i -e "s/.*:.*/&;/" INPUT_FILE.css
```

Some versions of sed don't support in-place editing (writing the output file to the input file):

```
sed -e "s/.*:.*/&;/" INPUT_FILE.css > OUTPUT_FILE.css
```

---

Explanation:

```
sed             invoke Stream EDitor commmand line tool
-i              edit in-place
-e              the next string will be the regular expression: s/.*:.*/&;/
INPUT_FILE.css  the name of your text file
```

The regular expression (RegEx) explained, in detail:

```
s   RegEx command indicates substitution
/   RegEx delimiter: separates command and match expression
.*  any string followed by...
:   a colon character followed by...
.*  any string
/   RegEx delimiter: separates match expression and replacement expression
&   RegEx back reference, entire string that was matched by match expression
;   the semicolon you wish to add
/   RegEx delimiter: ends replacement expression
```

Comment: This is useful for converting many files at one time

Answer (score 3):

In Vim, or any other editor with decent support for regular expressions

```
:%s/\(:.*\)$/\1;/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/:/s/$/;/' -cx file
```

1. `g` global search
2. `s` substitute
3. `$` end of line
4. `x` save and close